# Save screenshot using keyboard callback event

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am trying to save screenshot inside PCL Visualizer window using keyboard callback event. Below is the code snippet:

```
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

void keyboardEventOccurred (const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent &event, void* viewer)
{
  if (event.getKeySym () == "s" && event.keyDown ())
  {
    viewer->saveScreenshot("Image.png");
  }
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr body (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("body.pcd", *body);
    viewer.addPointCloud (body,"body");
    viewer.registerKeyboardCallback (keyboardEventOccurred, &viewer);
    viewer.spin();
    return 0;
}
```

However, there is some mismatch between data fields and it is returning following error:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer.dir/pcl_visualizer.cpp.o
/home/ravi/pcl_visualizer/pcl_visualizer.cpp: In function ‘void keyboardEventOccurred(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*)’:
/home/ravi/pcl_visualizer/pcl_visualizer.cpp:8:11: error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
     viewer->saveScreenshot("Image.png");
           ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer.dir/pcl_visualizer.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Any workaround, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you have is telling you everything really;  The point of void* in your callback is that it the callback provider doesn't know, or care, what type of pointer is being used for the callback.

You seem to pass it a pointer to the viewer object, but all the compiler knows or cares about is that it's an n bit number that represents some memory to provide to the callback.

By removing the concept of type by using void*, there's no way for the compiler to establish what is meant by viewer->XXX.

To resolve the problem, the easiest way is to cast the pointer to be what you think it should be; something like

```
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer* v = static_cast<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer*>(viewer)
```

you can then do v->XXX()

On a side note, I would also suggest you brush up on your pointers in your C++ book.

Comment: Ohhh... that was really important. It totally slipped my mind. Thank you very much for the nice explanation. it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is too late but this will fix it, (compiler needs to know the type of the object pointed to is PCLVisualizer class to know that saveScreenshot method is part of it otherwise it cannot guess):

```
void keyboardEventOccurred(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent& event, void* viewer)
{

    if (event.getKeySym() == "s" && event.keyDown())
    {
        ((pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer*)viewer)->saveScreenshot("Image.png");
    }
}
```